# Rewriting the code using % operator instead of if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was working on this code, and I got stuck here as a JS rookie and need help. How would you rewrite this block, using % operator, instead of if statement?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
 var letters = ["A","B","C"]
 var counter = 0;
 var timer=setInterval(
      function(){
      counter= counter+1;
      if (counter==letters.length){
          counter=0;
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").value=letters[counter];
      },1000)
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="demo" value="A">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `counter = (counter+1) % letters.length;`?

Answer (score 4):

Simple use it after doing your add operation to return the remains after division (or modulus):

```js
const letters = ["A","B","C"]

let counter = 0;

setInterval(function(){
  
  counter = (counter+1) % letters.length;
  document.getElementById("demo").value = letters[counter];

}, 1000);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="demo" value="A" />
```

Couple of other tips, use `const` if the values don't change (like your array), and `let` if it can definitely change. Also, you don't need to store your interval here as you never cancel it, so no need for `const timer` in that case. Simplifies the code a lot!

Comment: what if I use var, instead of const and let for declaring variables?

Comment: Its less descriptive. In essence it makes no difference, but const and let teach you about the intent of your variables.

Comment: (I want to add that there is a difference: you can't reassign to `const` variables - so doing `const a = 1; a = 2;` will result in an error. It's best when learning javascript that you use these new declarations as they tell you about how your code work and how it should be used. It's also clearer when you come back or for other developers later down the line)